# init.d script stop echo pipe to grep outputting to terminal

Tags: linux, bash, init.d

Is there anyway to silence the following command in an `init.d` script on `Amazon Linux`

```
response=`curl 'http://localhost:9200'`
if (echo "$response" | grep -e "\"status\" : 200"); then
... some logic
```

This command and conditional works as expected, however when the script is run `service scriptname start` the following is printed to the console

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   333  100   333    0     0  54278      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55500
  "status" : 200,
Starting scriptname                                            [  OK  ]
```

Ideally if possible I would like the display to only show:

```
Starting scriptname                                            [  OK  ]
```

Comment: `man curl  | grep -i -C 2 quiet` and `man grep | grep -i -C 2 quiet`

Answer (score 1):

Curl has a silent flag to stop it writing output to stdout and stderr. You can use either of:

```
curl -s
curl --silent
```

If you use the silent flag then the script will stop working as there is nothing for grep to find in the if statement. Use the following command which will look at the return value from curl instead of parsing its response:

```
if response=`curl -sS 'http://localhost:9200'`; then
... some logic
```

This will print nothing on success or an error message on failure. The response variable will contain all the data read from the request.

You can learn more about what curl can do on its [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/curl)

Comment: You can disregard the textual response and simply examine the exit code from `curl`. This is often a lot simpler and more robust.

Comment: Totally agree, I had a draft with this as an answer, I shall resurrect it